# Read @XmlValue as String without marhsalling/unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I have an XML object XMLAttribute which contains String name and String value attributes

```
 @XmlValue
  public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

@XmlAttribute(
    name = "name",
    required = true
  )
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
```

This value can be any String, but also an XML text which I want to get as it is without marhalling/unmarshalling. For example:

```
 <attribute name="PREFERENCES">
     <gprs>
       <pdp context-id="1" name="name1"/>
     </gprs>
 </attribute>
```

or

```
<attribute name="PROFILE">test_profile</attribute>
```

What I want to do is to get the value (XML text) of the PREFERENCES attribute as a String, but I always get null, probably because it's trying to marshall/unmarshall the XML whenever there is an XML opening/closing tag but the expected object is String. For the second example in which there is no XML in value I get the correct String.

Am I using the wrong annotations and is it possible to do this without changing the value to Object?

Thanks

Comment: You can’t do that with jaxb annotations. Your source xml would have to have the content wrapped in a CDATA section.

Comment: @Strelok I wasn't aware of this CDATA section, but it solved my problem! Thanks